# How can I mock an object instantiated in the constructor?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm writing unit-tests with Pytest. I want to unit-test a class that has on its `__init__` method an object that connects to a database:

**data_model.py**

```
from my_pkg.data_base_wrapper import DataBaseWrapper

class DataModel:
  def __init__(self):
    self.db = DataBaseWrapper()
    self.db.update_data()

  def foo(self):
    data = self.db.get_some_data()
    # make some processing and return a result
```

**data_base_wrapper.py**

```
class DataBaseWrapper:
  def __init__(self):
    # Init process of the wrapper
    pass

  def update_data(self):
    # Connect to the database and perform some operations
    pass
```

I've tried using `monkeypatch` on the `DataBaseWrapper` object of `DataModel`:

```
from my_pkg.data_model import DataModel

class MockDataBaseWrapper:
  @staticmethod
  def update_cache():
      pass

  @staticmethod
  def get_table(table):
    # Return some data for testing
    pass

@pytest.fixture
def data_model(monkeypatch):
  monkeypatch.setattr(DataModel, 'db', MockDataBaseWrapper)
  data_model = DataModel()

  return data_model
```

However, I get the following error:

```
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f10221669e8>

    @pytest.fixture
    def data_model(monkeypatch):
>       monkeypatch.setattr(DataModel, 'db', MockDataBaseWrapper)
E       AttributeError: <class 'dashboard.datamodel.DataModel'> has no attribute 'db'
```

I've read in the answers of similar questions, that I could try writing a sub-class of my `DataBaseWrapper` and change it on the `DataModel` class, but I'm in the same situation, as I cannot `monkeypatch` the attribute of the `__init__` method. I can, though, if it is not in the `__init__` method.

How can I write tests for this composition of classes? Suggestions on how to rewrite these classes or a different patter are also welcome.

Comment: Make your code easier to test: instead of hard-coding `DataBaseWrapper` inside `__init__`, have `DataModel.__init__` take as an argument the value to use for `self.db`, or a class which can be called to set `self.db` (e.g. def __init__(self, factory): self.db = factory()`)

Comment: In the fixture, make an instance of `DataModel` first then patch the `db` attribute on the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `MockDataBaseWrapper` is totally unrelated to the `DataBaseWrapper` used in `DataModel`.

My proposal is to get rid of your `MockDataBaseWrapper` and:

- If you want to keep your current structure, you can use `patch` to mock the `DataBaseWrapper` that is actually imported in data_model.py.

```
from mock import patch
from my_pkg.data_model import DataModel

def test_data_model():
    with patch("my_pkg.data_model.DataBaseWrapper") as MockedDB:
        mocked_db = MockedDB()
        data_model = DataModel()
        assert data_model.db is mocked_db
```

The `patch` context manager will replace the `DataBaseWrapper` class that gets imported in your data_model.py with a Mock instance and let you interact with that mock, which allows me here to verify that it got instantiated.

> Note that it is very important to patch the class in the module where it is imported (and not in the model where it is defined, i.e we patch `your_package.data_model.DataBaseWrapper` and not `your_package.data_base_wrapper.DataBaseWrapper`)

- If you don't mind changing your class, then the usual pattern is to inject the `db` parameter into the constructor of `DataModel`. Mocking it then becomes a piece of cake.

```
class DataModel:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
        self.db.update_data()
```

```
from mock import patch, Mock
from my_pkg.data_model import DataModel

def test_data_model():
    mocked_db = Mock()
    data_model = DataModel(mocked_db)
    assert data_model.db is mocked_db
```

Comment: Despite I've finally gone with the second approach (changed my class definition) I'm interesting in understanding the first one. I guess that `MockedDB` is defined in the test file itself, right? (I think it can be a good addition for future readers of the answer, for completeness)

Comment: I've clarified the answer, let me know if that's more understandable like this